# How to remove empty attributes "N/A" in Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, attributes

I am using Magento 2 with Porto theme, I recently updated theme and magento now in product information I am also seeing empty attributes that are unrelated to the current products as N/A . how can I hide them?

I saw people discussing here this in Magento 1. but it doesn't work for 2.0.

please help if you know how to do it. thanks

Answer (score 2):

The appearance of the N/A's is the product attributes occurred because of a change in \vendor\magento\module-catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes.php Line 90 that now calls the Phrase function:  if (($value instanceof Phrase || is_string($value)) && strlen($value)) {

Since this is a core file, changing it back and extending it to your theme not recommended. Instead, I extended the Magento_Catalog module to my theme and edited the attributes.phtml to look like the code sample below.

```
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
    <?php $_dataVal = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']); ?>
    <?php if ($_dataVal <> 'N/A'): ?>
        <?php if (is_numeric($_dataVal) == true): ?>
            <?php $_dataVal = number_format($_dataVal,2,'.',''); ?>
            <?php $_dataVal = substr($_dataVal, -3) == ".00" ? substr($_dataVal, 0, -3) : $_dataVal; ?>
        <?php endif;?>
        <tr class="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->escapeHtml(__($_data['code'])) ?>">
            <th class="col label" scope="row"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->escapeHtml(__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
            <td class="col data" data-th="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->escapeHtml(__($_data['label'])) ?>"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_dataVal ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endif;?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Would you please elaborate on what your code does. It seems it does more than just not display values with "No". It seems it also rounds numbers, no?

Comment: Yes, there is a little more going on there. Basically, I first check to see if the value is not 'N/A'. If the value is 'N/A', nothing is returned. 

If it is not 'N/A', I check to see if it's numeric. If it is numeric and the last three characters are .00 then I strip them off. Then I return the label and the data in their html format.